# Mexendo com data e hora em PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

estou com uma dúvida. Gostaria de saber como eu consigo fazer para que o código php armazene a hora que eu registrei uma atividade, porém ela deve ficará oculta no formulário e somente visível quando estes dados forem visíveis em uma tabela.

```html
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

  <?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) : ?>
    <blockquote> Registrado com sucesso! </blockquote>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <h2>Registrar Atividade</h2>

  <form method="post">
    <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
    <label for="nome_atividade">Nome da Atividade: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nome_atividade" id="nome_atividade">
    <label for="duracao">Duração: </label>
    <input type="text" name="duracao" id="duracao">
    <label for="descricao">Descrição: </label>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="descricao" id="descricao"></textarea> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Registrar">
  </form>
  
  <a href="registro_de_atividades.php">Voltar</a> <br>
  <a href="index.php">Voltar para o meu perfil</a> <br>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Nem precisa ficar oculta no formulário, basta o servidor que recebe essa informação salvar a hora junto com os dados do formulário. Você pode usar a função [`date()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Exemplo: `date(""Y-m-d H:i:s"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta que no seu arquivo *registro_de_atividades.php*, ao qual você envia os dados do formulário, você crie uma variável que receba uma função de data, pegando a data e hora corrente. Segue exemplo:

```
// aqui crio a variável $data e atribuo a função do php date(), passando a formatação de data desejada (no caso, no padrão de data do banco de dados)
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// ... no seu SQL de registro passe a variável como valor do campo de data de registro
```

Segue a documentação da função *date*: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php